# Detecting Openlayers features using Cypress

Tags: javascript, openlayers, cypress

How can I check for features on an Openlayers map within a Cypress test?

I have tried assigning the map object to a global variable but Cypress can't pick it up:

```
    // openlayers file
    window.olMap = MapInstance;

    // cypress spec
    cy.window().then(window => {
        console.log(window.olMap.getLayers()); // typeerror olMap is undefined, yet I can see it in cypress console
    });
```

Is there a better way to detect features within Cypress?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You usage seems okay, and the `olMapt` does exist in the window object. Maybe that's something wrong in the olMap?

Comment: I didn't realise Cypress is async and so the console is readable after the test has already run, will add the answer in now, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Due to the asyncronous nature of Cypress the map must be loaded before the test continues, this is how I solved it:

```
    // Add in this get method which will wait until load
    cy.get(".ol-viewport");

    cy.window().then(win => {
        const layers = win.olMap.getLayers().getArray();
        console.log(layers); // Displays list of layers
    });
```